# the keydown event is not allowing typing the in the textarea?

Tags: jquery

Using the logic below I can't type information in the textarea

```
     $(document).keydown(function(event)
     {
          var key = event.keyCode || event.which;

          if(key == tab)
          {
          } else if(key == rightArrow)
          {
          } else if(key == leftArrow)
          {
          }else
          {
          }
     });
```

But using this logic below, I'm able to type information into the textarea but the tab and rightArrow and leftArrow is not working.

```
     $(document).keydown(function(event)
     {
          var key = event.keyCode || event.which;

          if(key == tab)
          {
          } else if(key == rightArrow)
          {
          } else if(key == leftArrow)
          {
          }else
          {
              $(document).unbind('keydown');
          }
     });
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://jsbin.com/ozacof/1/edit), typing still works with the first code sample in effect (added logging to console to confirm the actual invocation of the event handler).

Answer (score 0):

You can't just test for tab or leftArrow or rightArrow. [You need to use keycodes.](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

```
 $(document).keydown(function(event){
     tab = 9;
     leftArrow = 37;
     rightArrow = 39;
     var key = event.keyCode || event.which;

     if(key == tab){
         console.log('tab');
     } else if(key == rightArrow){
         console.log('right');
     } else if(key == leftArrow){
         console.log('left');
     }else{
         console.log('else');
     }
});​
```

[Check it out here.](http://jsfiddle.net/x7nVC/)